# momentjs isBefore returns bad results

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to check if a given date is before today's date:

```
const today = moment(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD", true);
const isBeforeToday = moment("2016-08-20", "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isBefore(today));
```

`isBeforeToday` variable has the value of true, which is obviously not correct. Today is 20th of august and 20th of august IS NOT before 20th of august :). Any ideas?

Comment: And you can check just like: `const isBeforeToday = moment("2016-08-20").isBefore(moment()));`

Comment: @Hardy Nope, that will have the same issue. (`moment("2016-08-20").isBefore()` is the same thing, btw.) In the OP's case you'd still need the granularity modifier, so you still need to pass in the comparison date, though.

Comment: Yes, i know it has the same issue, but this is just shorter way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 20th of Aug isn't before the 20th of August, but:

You're constructing two different kinds of dates: one with time, one without, and midnight *is* (currently) before the current time.

```
const today = moment(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD", true)
console.log(JSON.stringify(today, null, 2))
// >> "2016-08-20T16:28:23.020Z"

const tmp = moment("2016-08-20", "YYYY-MM-DD", true)
console.log(JSON.stringify(tmp, null, 2));
// >> "2016-08-20T04:00:00.000Z"

const isBeforeToday = tmp.isBefore(today)
console.log(isBeforeToday);
// >> true
```

You're constructing your first moment with a `Date`, not a string; there's nothing to parse. Thus your moment has all the date fields. If you created your `Date` object without time fields you get what you expect:

```
const today2 = moment(new Date(2016, 07, 20), "YYYY-MM-DD", true)
console.log(JSON.stringify(today2, null, 2))
// >> "2016-08-20T04:00:00.000Z"

const tmp2 = moment("2016-08-20", "YYYY-MM-DD", true)
console.log(JSON.stringify(tmp2, null, 2));
// >> "2016-08-20T04:00:00.000Z"

const isBeforeToday2 = tmp2.isBefore(today2)
console.log(isBeforeToday2);
// >> false
```

Comment: So what the second parameter of `moment` constructor is for? I thought that it tells the parser to get only year, month and day.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch It does, but you're not passing it anything to format, you're passing a `Date`, not a string.

Comment: Oh, that explains a lot :). However you still haven't mentioned how to get desired results :). Fortunatelly I found it out myself minutes after asking this question - the `isBefore` method accepts a second argument that is telling the lib which accuracy it should use, so `isBefore(today, "day")` does the trick.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch In fairness, you didn't ask for anything other than an explanation.

Comment: I think it's implied what's my intention with this code. But since you gave an answer that would put me on a right track if I haven't looked at the documentation, I have no option, but to accept it :).

Comment: Consider `startOf('day')`

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch—you can write your own answer and accept that if you think it would be a better answer to the question.